# how to skip error in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, error-handling, multiprocessing

I use to run long independent jobs with multiprocessing.Pool.map

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
input_var = [1,2,3]
ris = pool.map(long_function,input_var)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This works well but if for example I get an error in `long_function(2)` I will lose all the information that I have obtained with `long_function(1)` and `long_function(3)`.

is there a way to avoid this?

The best would be to obtain an output like `ris=[long_function(1), ERROR, long_function(3)]` 
Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
def safe_long_function(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return long_function(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

You basically want to catch the exceptions thrown and then return them rather than raise them.
For example

```
def long_function(x):
    if x == 2:
        raise Exception("This number is even")

import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool() # default is num CPUs
input_var = [1,2,3]
ris = pool.map(safe_long_function, input_var)
pool.close()
pool.join()

print ris
```

This will give `[1, Exception("This number is even"), 3]`

You can then do something like

```
for result in ris:
    if isinstance(result, Exception):
        print "Error: %s" % result
    else:
        print result
```